# SQL JOIN Syntax Error with Multiple Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, syntax-error

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    [SQL].[dbo].[Debtors] d
JOIN 
    [SQL].[dbo].[DebtorIndex] di
JOIN 
    [SQL].[dbo].[DebtorAddresses] da ON d.IDNumber = di.IDNumber
                                     AND d.AutoNumber = da.DebtorID
                                     AND da.DebtorID = '199'
```

I am getting this error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near 'da'.

First however there is nothing there. Is there supposed to be something else there?

Second for `[SQL].[dbo].[Debtors] d`, I know for a fact and have triple checked that `d.IDNumber` & `d.AutoNumber` exist but I get the following error for both

> "The multi-part identifier "d.IDNumber" could not be bound."

and get the same for `d.AutoNumber`.

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the difference between `AutoNumber` and `IDNumber`? It sounds like they're both `IDENTITY` or primary-key attributes, in which case one is redundant. Also avoid using the term "Autonumber" as it doesn't apply to SQL Server.

Comment: That is a field that is in my data and is used as it is unique

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [SQL].[dbo].[Debtors] d
INNER JOIN [SQL].[dbo].[DebtorIndex] di ON d.IDNumber = di.IDNumber
INNER JOIN [SQL].[dbo].[DebtorAddresses] da ON d.AutoNumber = da.DebtorID
WHERE da.DebtorID = '199'
```

Comment: I did that but nothing shows up. When you type '199' something should show up when i do the searches manually however get no results when I do it with this sql statement

Comment: I'd have to look at the data to answer why

Answer (score 1):

You don’t have a join condition on di.

... di on d.something = di.anotherthing